# Geometric shapes

Tags: assembly, geometry, irvine32, geometric-arc

I am working on my project with assembly language I have a text file each line in the text contain 2 coordinates (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and this coordinates is a line i can draw , my task is to find the how many rectangles and how many squares and triangles these coordinates can make , So I have to find 4 intersections and this give me 1 rectangle and by checking the distance I can differentiate between square and rectangle and if i found 3 intersection so its a triangle 
my main problem is how to find the intersection

I read the text and saved the number in an array of struct of type line this line contain 4 variables which are x1,y1,x2,y2
by using this array of struct how can I find the intersections to find the number of each shape .

Comment: With 2 fixed points, there are an infinite number of triangles you can make, by placing a 3rd point anywhere except in the same line as the first 2.  If you're considering only 32-bit integer coordinates, you could look for common factors between the delta-x and delta-y to see how many points along the line intersect whole-integer grid points.  Is that really the problem you have to solve?  It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you give an example?

Comment: i think u didn't get what i mean , the problem here is that on each each line in the text file there exist coordinates of 2 points which makes a line between those 2 points after reading the whole file i would have many lines which i need a sort of condition to check what these multiple lines form as geometrical shape (rectangle-square-triangle)  , thank you

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: i have struct line { x1 byte , y1 byte , x2 byte , y2 byte }                               and i made an array of line  {(20,20,30,50),(10,10,50,50),(10,10,30,50),(20,20,40,20),(40,20,30,50),(40,20,40,60),(40,60,100,60),(100,50,105,50),(100,60,100,20),(100,20,40,20)}  and this is the values of the coordinates ...what is the conditions to  detect the result shapes from this intercepted line?